# Can you add a user to OneSignal after you deleted them?

Tags: push-notification, notifications, push, onesignal

A user was deleted from OneSignal by accident. How can i add that user again?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a mobile app, the user can install and run the app. He will then be added as a user.

Comment: The problem is that when a user is deleted from the onesignal dashboard and he installs and runs the app for a second time he won't be added.

Comment: Could you paste the code that registers the user in the app?